# How to query for a particular field of source in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have `elasticsearch` cluster running fine. When I run the below command, I get all the messages:

```
GET myindex/fluentd/_search?sort=@timestamp:desc
```

Now the above command gives me all the logs with respect to the timestamp in descending order. Below is the logs looks like:

```
{
    "_index": "myindex",
    "_type": "fluentd",
    "_id": "ZFVk8mMB3x3ftHjXD16B",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "datatime": "Jun 12 05:06:11",
      "username": "user1",
      "msg": "Running elasticsearch",
      "hostname": "user1",
      "@timestamp": "2018-06-12T05:06:11.000000000+00:00"
    },
    "sort": [
      1528779971000
    ]
```

},

What command can I run to extract just the `msg` field of the source from all the logs with respect to time in descending order?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried searching this on google.?

An easy search on google gave me the link to this [page](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html) which shows perfect example of doing this:

```
GET twitter/_doc/0?_source_include=*.id&_source_exclude=entities
```

Using `_source_include` you can get `msg` from your logs.

Comment: If you copy/paste an example from the web, try to at least modify it to fit the data in the OP's question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `_source` query string parameter like this:

```
GET myindex/fluentd/_search?sort=@timestamp:desc&_source=msg
```